# Kinetic js provides hit only inside a closed path on custom shapes

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

[image]I am unable to trigger events in the desired path.. Here is an simple example, when I draw a line and wanted to trigger hit on mouseover of that line... Kinetic js itself closes the line path and provides hit only inside the region and not on the region below the mid of the line..

Below is the code and plunkr..

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/orCEGKENFkqn6fIy3IjE?p=preview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a hit region on an unclosed Kinetic.line.**

But, the hit region is not the entire width of its stroke.

For example, set your lineWidth to 60 and notice that your hit region becomes bigger.

Comment: I think u mis understood the question.. the region in between V shaped line acts as hit region...and the bottom half from the centre of the line wont be listening to the hit..

Comment: I see, you wanted the bottom portion of the line to be a hit region.  Here's the problem...Html canvas (and Kinetic) lines are always drawn half inside a path and half outside a path.  Therefore, hit testing on a line will work only on the "inside" half of a line and not the "outside" (bottom) half.

Comment: yup that is correct... but when we look into the Kinetic.Line behaviour it works perfect on the upper as well the lower half... I just want to mimic tat behaviour for my custom shapes as well..

Comment: Yes, they behave differently...Kinetic.Shape draws/hittests with a wrapper around a standard html canvas context where Kinetic.Line is coded in a non-standard (but more friendly) way.